# Should I use Entity Views Attach module to solve my problem

Tags: panels, entities, views

I've check the question in this node: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-entity-views-attach-module

And I see that maybe what is answered there is a partial solution to the issue I'm facing. To avoid writing I will paste the issues addresses I've been creating on my help search:

1. https://drupal.org/node/1928064
2. https://drupal.org/node/1929030
3. https://drupal.org/node/332001

Basically it's to send an argument from a view to another view, both displayed at the same time in the same page (one in block, the other in content). A further complication is that those views are contained in panels.

On the "block view", there is a list of let's say names (extracted from a content type) exposed as links which point to the "content view". This takes the argument (text of the link) from the clicked link of the "block view" as a filter to display some others fields from the same content type.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might get a better answer if you were to say more about what you are trying to achieve than how you are doing so.

For example, reading between the lines of your question I wonder if you are working on some sort of faceted search? In which case I'd recommend you look at [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api). And this may be of interest: http://ygerasimov.com/ajaxified-solr-search-drupal-search-api-views-panels

Comment: Addendum: if all you need is to create links from one view to another, using results field values in the links as arguments to the other view, Views already allows you to do this. One of the options for field output is "Rewrite as link", and this enables you to craft the URLs as you like. You just need to ensure that all the values you need are present in the list of fields ahead of the one you are rewriting. Any you don't want to display should have the Exclude from view option on.

Comment: I didn't add more details because, as I tell, they are at the links I share, any way, here is and image http://parles.upf.edu/llocs/proves/views&panels.png of what I'm loking for, by the way, it is what you describe in the addendum, but with the furder complication that views are contained in panels.

Comment: I describe the image and content from where the views gets the data in here: Content type: "translation record" in this content you enter information by translation, I mean if I have Robinson Crusoe translated by "Translator 1" (that's the name of the translator, could have been John White, for instance), I enter next info in the "Translation record 1"= Piece of work: Robinson Crusoe - Author: Daniel Defoe - Translator: Translator 1.

Comment: "Translation record 2"= Piece of work: Orlando - Author: Virginia Wolf - Translator: Translator 2. "Translation record 3"= Piece of work: Henry IV - Author: William Shakespeare - Translator: Translator 1. Etc. So the view that is contained at the left side block shows the "translator" field of the "Translation record" content type, and the view on the content side should show the "piece of work" and "author" fields of that same content when the "Translator 1" is clicked at the block side view. I hope this info is clearer.

Comment: The View display should be a content pane, then you need to configure its Argument input setting to be "from panel argument", and choose the number you want. If your panel path is set to 'foo' and the path with the argument is 'foo/bah' then the argument you want to configure is 'First'.

Comment: So you need to put the translator ID (a uid or nid depending on whether a translator is defined as a user or a node) on the link and then use the argument mechanism I describe to pass it as a contextual filter to the view.

Comment: Hi Alfred,I got nothing on the  Argument input, check this pic: http://parles.upf.edu/llocs/proves/Argument_input-setting.png. So what I'm doing wrong, by the way, at the block that list the translators I get their name as many times as contens have them, is there a way to GROUP BY 'field_data_field_translator' (as in MySql) in the resulting view? Thanks again

Comment: Did you add a contextual filter? (Contextual filter is another name for argument, it changed in Drupal 7 but many parts of the UI still talk about arguments). And you can configure Views to do grouping on the settings for the format of your view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7820/discussion-between-andres-chandia-and-alfred-armstrong)